# How to append certain columns of all rows of data frame to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes:

```
dataframe_1:
              A B C D
              1 E 2 F
              3 G 4 H



dataframe_2:
              A B C D
              5 I 6 J
              7 K 8 L

df_columns = ['username', 'reason']
dataframe_3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns)
```

and I want to add all rows in `dataframe_1` and `dataframe_2` into `dataframe_3`
But mapped as followed:

```
dataframe_3.append(dataframe_1['A','reason 1'])
dataframe_3.append(dataframe_2['A','reason 2'])
```

To end up with:

```
  dataframe_3:
               username reason
               1        reason 1
               3        reason 1
               5        reason 2
               7        reason 2
```

So essentially use column `A` and map that to `username` and have a specific reason for each dataframe.

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
(pd.concat((df1[['A']].assign(reason='reason 1'), 
            df2[['A']].assign(reason='reason 2'))
          )
   .rename(columns={'A':'username'})
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to only concat only certain columns? Because  `df1` and `df2` have more than just the column `A` and `reason`

Comment: Do you mean replacing `['A']` with, say `['A','B','C']`?

Comment: I don't want `B`, `C` and `D` part of the new dataframe

Comment: Sorry! You're right, I missed the `[['A']]` portion of the code

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1, 3], 'B': ['E', 'G'], 'C': [2, 4], 'D': ['F', 'H']})


dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [5, 7], 'B': ['I', 'K'], 'C': [6, 8], 'D': ['J', 'L']})

df_columns = ['username', 'reason']
dataframe_3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns)

for count, number in enumerate(dataframe_1['A']):
    dataframe_3.at[count, 'username'] = number
    dataframe_3.at[count, 'reason'] = 'reason 1'

for count, number in enumerate(dataframe_2['A'], count + 1):
    dataframe_3.at[count, 'username'] = number
    dataframe_3.at[count, 'reason'] = 'reason 2'

print(dataframe_3)
```

Output:

```
  username    reason
0        1  reason 1
1        3  reason 1
2        5  reason 2
3        7  reason 2
```